# How to learn ip of raspberry pi (raspbian lite)

Tags: raspberry-pi, ip, raspbian

I tried all ways. But I couldn't. I did scan on angry scanner and advanced ip scanner. But The raspberry pi does not look.I connect to pi with cable

Answer (score 0):

Run arp to get all your devices. On Linux:

```
/usr/sbin/arp -n
```

On Windows:

```
arp -a
```

Than try to identify your Pi. Probably there will be not that much.
Than you can connect with SSH.

Another way will be to connect display, than you will have a login to console immediately. Than run ifconfig to find out ip.

Comment: But I did install raspbian lite to raspberry pi. Can I connect display ?

Comment: There's no magic. It's just a simple PC. You can connect display to it even if there's no OS at all.

Comment: Thanks. It seems, I need a keyboard. :)

Comment: You can connect with putty if you managed to "arp" the ip. There's no need in display/keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Angry IP Scanner works fine for me, but some routers by default will block all traffic from wireless to wired clients. This usually can be disabled in you router gui. After you disable it, Angry should work fine.

The other easiest way to find IP of Raspberry PI would be:

- to login to your router and then check under DHCP options what
  computers are using what IPs
- login to Raspberry PI, open terminal and write "ifconfig"